# How to setup real time streaming in power BI?

Tags: azure, streaming, powerbi

I am  creating a dashboard with database that is hosted on Azure, I can setup a connection with azure database in power bi desktop but real time streaming is not possible in case of power bi desktop. It's possible if I create a dashboard in Power BI online. 
But in power bi online I don't have option for data modeling. I want to know is there any way I can perform some data modelling or transformation ?

Please provide some link also if possible.
Thanks for your time.